# Finding mass density of a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

> If the gravitational field vector is independent of the radial
>   distance within a sphere, find the function describing the mass
>   density $\rho (r)$ of the sphere.

I uses the divergence of $\bf g$:

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot\vec g &= 4\pi G\rho \\
g &= -GM\frac {\hat r}{r^2}
\end{align}$$
so I can take the divergence which is (using spherical)
$$\nabla \cdot \vec g=-4\pi G M$$
So $\rho=-M$

This does not make sense to me at all.  The mass density should be in units of mass/volume, but I just get mass.  Any help as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: What David Z said, and you also may want to reconsider your interpretation of "the gravitational field vector is independent of the radial distance within a sphere". Judging by how you used that info, you probably didn't quite get what the question meant by that.

Comment: Hmmmm.  Then what does the question want/

Comment: If you really can't understand what "the gravitational field vector is independent of the radial distance within a sphere" means, you could ask a separate question about that. But think about it first. It just means what it says.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  That just means that if $\nabla g = \phi$, then $\frac {d\phi}{dr}=Constant$

Comment: So I can then just apply the divergence equation in spherical.

Comment: No, you're skipping ahead and making mistakes. "the gravitational field vector is independent of the radial distance within a sphere". $g$ is the gravitational field vector, right? It's independent of the radial distance, right? That means whether you are 1m away from the centre of the sphere or 3m away the field is equally strong. How does your equation represent that?

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this, you should back up step by step from the point at which you notice a unit problem. At each step, check the units in the equation and see if they are consistent. If they are, then you know you made a mistake after that step; if you get to the first step and you find inconsistent units, you know you're using an incorrect equation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\vec g = g_r\hat r$ and $g_r=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}$ is a constant, then taking the divergence$$\nabla \cdot \vec g=\frac{1}{r^2 \sin\theta}[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(g_rr^2\sin\theta)+\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(g_\theta r\sin\theta )+\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(g_\phi r)]$$
$$=\frac{2g_r}{r}=4\pi G\rho(r)$$
$$\Rightarrow \rho(r)=\frac{g_r}{2\pi Gr}$$